# Prevent ng-click from firing for confirmation dialog (stopped working in Angular 1.2 RC3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick, confirm, directive

I'm using this script to have a confirmation dialog before actually firing the ng-click function

```
Directives.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
  function(){
    return {
      priority: 100,
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(e){
          var message = attrs.ngConfirmClick;
          if(message && !confirm(message)){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

as seen on
http://zachsnow.com/#!/blog/2013/confirming-ng-click/

it's used via:

```
<button ng-confirm-click="Are you sure?" ng-click="remove()">Remove</button>
```

There are other similar scripts here on SO, but **since i updated to Angular 1.2 RC3 they stopped working**. The ng-click function is always fired BEFORE the actual link function is stepped into.

I also tried to increase *priority* and to listen to other events(touchstart, because the newest angular has this new ngtouch directives). But nothing works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Ah i got it solved myself**!

Recently there was a commit by the angular team that changed the pre/post linking priority:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/31f190d4d53921d32253ba80d9ebe57d6c1de82b

This is now included in Angular 1.2 RC3!

Therefore the post linking function has now a reversed priority.

So there are two ways to solve this.
Either **use a negative priority now**

```
Directives.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
  function(){
    return {
      priority: -100,  //<---------
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(e){
          var message = attrs.ngConfirmClick;
          if(message && !confirm(message)){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

OR **convert the function to a pre linking function**

```
Directives.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
  function(){
    return {
      priority: 100,
      restrict: 'A',
      link: {
          pre: function(scope, element, attrs){ //<---------
                element.bind('click touchstart', function(e){
                  var message = attrs.ngConfirmClick;
                  if(message && !window.confirm(message)){
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                  }
                });
              }
        }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: i used the latter approach and converted it to a pre linking function, seems more natural to me than to have negative priority

Comment: Neither of these work in angular 1.2.15. You see the confirmation dialog but it doesn't stop the event propagation. Any idea why?

Comment: Sry for the late answer, but maybe it helps others. We use angular 1.2.16 and here it workes as expected exactly as described above.

Comment: Yup that works with 1.2.21 and it's *so clean*, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! life savior!!

Comment: I totally forgot about prelinking function and was even trying to set the priority to 1 billion. Thanks